# Configuring multiple QComboBoxes

Tags: qt

I have a basic question. I have combo boxes with name `comboBox_frequency_1`, `comboBox_frequency_2`,`comboBox_frequency_3`,`comboBox_frequency_4`, `comboBox_frequency_5` etc.

I need to add items to each combo box as below:

```
    ui->comboBox_frequency_1->addItem("10Hz", QVariant(100));
    ui->comboBox_frequency_1->addItem("15Hz", QVariant(150));
    ui->comboBox_frequency_1->addItem("20Hz", QVariant(200));
    ui->comboBox_frequency_1->addItem("25Hz", QVariant(250));
    ui->comboBox_frequency_1->addItem("30Hz", QVariant(300));
```

What is the easiest method to do the same settings to other combo boxes by using for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of those UI elements and iterate over that like so:

```
QComboBox* boxes[] { ui->comboBox_frequency_1, ui->comboBox_frequency_2, ui->comboBox_frequency_3, ui->comboBox_frequency_4, ui->comboBox_frequency_5 };
for(auto* cb : boxes)
{
    cb->addItem("10Hz", QVariant(100));
    cb->addItem("15Hz", QVariant(150));
    cb->addItem("20Hz", QVariant(200));
    cb->addItem("25Hz", QVariant(250));
    cb->addItem("30Hz", QVariant(300));
}
```

You may want to create those QComboBoxes in code instead of the UI file if you have such a long list of them, so you can store them in an array at creation and don't have to name them individually.

Also, it's possible to replace the block of `addItem`s with a loop and a table. That may or may not be more readable depending on size of the table.

```
QComboBox* boxes[] { ui->comboBox_frequency_1, ui->comboBox_frequency_2, ui->comboBox_frequency_3, ui->comboBox_frequency_4, ui->comboBox_frequency_5 };
const int values[] { 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 };
for(auto* cb : boxes)
{
    for(auto val : values)
    {
        cb->addItem(QString::number(val) + "Hz", QVariant(val*10));
    }
}
```